# Proton affinities in machine readable format?

Tags: organic-chemistry, ions, cheminformatics

Short: How to get **proton affinities** for a large list of chemicals? A database? A programming API?

Longer:

I have ca. 2000 chemicals (downloaded from [MCM](http://mcm.leeds.ac.uk/MCM/), mostly organics that occur in the atmosphere and their reaction products). I would like to try to get proton affinities for as many of the 2000 chemicals as possible.

I know how to look up the proton affinity for a chemical in the NIST Chemistry WebBook ([for example isoprene](http://webbook.nist.gov/cgi/cbook.cgi?ID=C78795&Units=SI&Mask=20#Ion-Energetics)). But I would prefer to get a machine readable database, or a Python API (or any programming language), to get these nicely in a program code.

What options do I have?

(I am not going to get 2000 values by hand, so my last option would be to write a small web scraper to make these 2000 web queries)

Answer (score 5):

To my knowledge, a (Python) API for the NIST chemistry WebBook does not exist.

Rather than filling out the [Search for Species Data by CAS Registry Number](http://webbook.nist.gov/chemistry/cas-ser.html) by hand, you might want to use `mechanize`.

But since you're only interested in **Gas phase ion energetics data** anyway, you might want to construct the relevant URLs directly.

Isoprene:

http://webbook.nist.gov/cgi/cbook.cgi?ID=C78795&Units=SI&Mask=20#Ion-Energetics

Styrene:

http://webbook.nist.gov/cgi/cbook.cgi?ID=C100425&Units=SI&Mask=20#Ion-Energetics

The parameter pattern is obvious: ID is the CAS number of the compound minus the dashes, prefixed by **C**.

Comment: What is `mechanize`?

Comment: @SampoSmolander Mechanize is a Python module to emulate a browser and fill out forms, even the cgi stuff on the NISTwebBook sites. But you're probably better off to construct the URLs based on the CAS numbers, use `urllib2` or `requests` to pull the data and process it with BeautifulSoup. A decent API would make our lives much easier!

Comment: Ah ok, ['mechanize'](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/) is a Python thing, not a chemistry thing.

Comment: Anyway, I am not limited to the NIST web data. If there would exist any other machine readable database containing this information, I could also use that. NIST is just the only thing (besides 19 pages in PDF from CRC Handbook) I found.